# How to get current date data only from API

Tags: android, api, date, current-time

I'm creating an app which calls an API through volley
API: `http://cricapi.com/api/matches?apikey=<my API key>`

After calling this API I'm getting all the data today and after.My question is, I want to get only current date (Today) data only.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<Model> modelList;
    private String url = "http://cricapi.com/api/matches?apikey=<key>";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        loadUrlData();
    }
    private void loadUrlData() {
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading ...");
        pd.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                pd.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("matches");
                    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        try {
                            String uniqueid=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("unique_id");
                            String team1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("team-1");
                            String team2=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("team-2");
                            String matchType=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("type");
                            String matchStatus=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("matchStarted");
                            if (matchStatus.equals("true")){
                                matchStatus="Match Started";
                            }else {
                                matchStatus="Match not started";
                            }
                            String dateTimeGMT=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("dateTimeGMT");
                            SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
                          format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(dateTimeGMT));
                            Date date=format1.parse(dateTimeGMT);
                            SimpleDateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                            format2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                            String dateTime=format2.format(date);
                            Model model=new Model(uniqueid,team1,team2,matchType,matchStatus,dateTime);
                            modelList.add(model);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"" +e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    adapter=new MyAdapter(modelList,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"" +e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error:" +error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you cannot filter it on the server side, you can filter it on the client side

Comment: @svkaka   how can i filter from client side

Comment: You posted the API key along with the URL in your question. I've flagged for moderator attention to have it redacted, but I highly recommend you change it anyways (it has likely been picked up by various web crawlers/scrapers)

Comment: @svkaka  how can i fetch specific data from web service in client side

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed cricapi. There is no information about the dates. You already get all the data. You should handle it in your app. You can handle with a loop. Or you can try to filter with gson type adapter ([custom adapter example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gson/gson_custom_adapters.htm))

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<Model> modelList;
    private String url = "http://cricapi.com/api/matches?apikey=<key>";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        loadUrlData();
    }
    private void loadUrlData() {
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading ...");
        pd.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                pd.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new 
       JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("matches");
                    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        try {
   dateTimeGMT=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("dateTimeGMT");
   if(dateTimeGMT.equals(TODAY)){
                            String uniqueid=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("unique_id");
                            String team1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("team-1");
                            String team2=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("team-2");
                            String matchType=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("type");
                            String matchStatus=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("matchStarted");
                            if (matchStatus.equals("true")){
                                matchStatus="Match Started";
                            }else {
                                matchStatus="Match not started";
                            }
                            SimpleDateFormat format1=new 
                     SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
                          format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(dateTimeGMT));
                            Date date=format1.parse(dateTimeGMT);
                            SimpleDateFormat format2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                            format2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                            String dateTime=format2.format(date);
                            Model model=new Model(uniqueid,team1,team2,matchType,matchStatus,dateTime);
                            modelList.add(model);
                  }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"" +e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    adapter=new MyAdapter(modelList,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                 }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"" +e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error:" +error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i handle with a loop ?

Comment: `fori(...){
    if(today.equals(responseModel.date())){
       //your code
    }
}`

Comment: I added. You should get today and use instead of TODAY